# Runtime Exception Android

Tags: android

I am having a strange error in my application , i am getting NULL Exception in the below code , sometimes (YES it sometimes , sounds strange !!!)

Please have a look

```
String appId = preferences.getString(ProjectConstants.IMEI_NO, null);
    if (appId == null) {
        // Here i am getting exception:
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        appId = manager.getDeviceId();
        preferences.edit().putString(ProjectConstants.IMEI_NO, appId);
    }
```

Logcat

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.homeshop18.service.GSONfunctions.getGSONfromURL(GSONfunctions.java:115)
 at com.homeshop18.ui.myorder.MyOrdersFragment$DownloadMyOrders.doInBackground(MyOrdersFragment.java:92)
 at com.homeshop18.ui.myorder.MyOrdersFragment$DownloadMyOrders.doInBackground(MyOrdersFragment.java:1)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) ... 5 more
```

Any help would be appreciated .. :D

Comment: can you specify the line...??

Comment: logcat would be helpful

Comment: @umair.ali :  TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

Comment: probabaly you are not passing right 'context' to you java class...try NameOfYourCallingActivity.this in the place where you are initiating this class...

Comment: @umair.ali : Not its not like that .. its happening sometimes .. got this error for Google Analytic ,not getting in Logcat ...

Comment: Can you share the code for the whole class? It seems that this is related to the context being null.

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat log clearly shows,

> at
>   com.homeshop18.service.GSONfunctions.getGSONfromURL(GSONfunctions.java:115)

Please check at line no 115, there is something null and you are trying to access its property.

Update, if your first code snippet is from `GSONfunctions`, you must check `context` is null or not.